# parse C# preprocessors in antlr4

Tags: c#, antlr4

I'm trying to parse C# preprocessors using ANTLR4 instead of ignoring them. I'm using the grammar mentioned here: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/csharp

This is my addition (now i'm focusing only on pp_conditional):

```
pp_directive
    : Pp_declaration
    | pp_conditional
    | Pp_line
    | Pp_diagnostic
    | Pp_region
    | Pp_pragma
    ; 

pp_conditional
    : pp_if_section (pp_elif_section | pp_else_section | pp_conditional)*  pp_endif
;


pp_if_section:
  SHARP 'if' conditional_or_expression statement_list
;

pp_elif_section: 
   SHARP 'elif' conditional_or_expression statement_list
;

pp_else_section:
   SHARP 'else' (statement_list | pp_if_section)
;

pp_endif:
    SHARP 'endif'
;
```

I added its entry here:

```
block 
    : OPEN_BRACE statement_list? CLOSE_BRACE
    | pp_directive
    ;
```

i'm getting that error:

```
line 19:0 mismatched input '#if TEST\n' expecting '}'
```

when i use the following test case:

```
if (!IsPostBack){
 #if TEST 
   ltrBuild.Text = "**TEST**"; 

#else 
   ltrBuild.Text = "**LIVE**";

#endif
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a `block` is composed of either `'{' statement_list? '}'` or a `pp_directive`. In this specific case, it chooses the first, because the first token it sees is a `{` (after the `if` condition). Now, it is expecting to maybe see a `statement_list?` and then a `}`, but what it find is `#if TEST`, a `pp_directive`.

What do we have to do? Make your `pp_directive` a statement. Since we know `statement_list: statement+;`, we search for `statement` and add `pp_directive` to it:

```
statement 
    : labeled_statement
    | declaration_statement
    | embedded_statement
    | pp_directive
    ;
```

And it should be working fine. However, we must also see if your `block: ... | pp_directive` should be removed or not, and it should be. I'll let it for you to find out why, but here's a test case that's ambiguous:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
    #pragma X
else {
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried what you have suggested and still the same error exists.

Comment: @Hamzawey are you sure you are recompiling both grammars? I don't think Antlr is correct is this diagostics.

Comment: yes, i even cleaned the whole solution and rebuild it.